# Question about tracking down the use of ::marker

Tags: css, firefox, css-selectors, pseudo-class

It is my understanding that any CSS selector with ::name is a pseudo-class and needs to be used as part of a tag selector, ex. li::marker. I have recently run into some code that has ::marker outside the tag.

Here is how it shows in Page View

```
<li id="menu-item-435" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-435"><a href="https://URL/">Latest Post</a></li>
```

Here is how it shows in the Firefox Inspector

```
<li id="menu-item-435" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-435">::marker<a href="https://URL/">Latest Post</a></li>
```

What is the difference?

Comment: You are confusing pseudo classes with pseudo elements. ::marker is a pseudo element.

Comment: *into some code that has ::marker outside the tag.* --> it's inside a tag in the code you are showing

Comment: The tip about pseudo classes v pseudo elements is very helpful! I did some research before posting. Now, I am wondering whether I may have read the resources incorrect.

Comment: To be honest, a lot of resources get this wrong, too, so it's not entirely your fault. Having said that, I am not sure of a satisfactory way to answer this question.

Comment: I will be rolling back around to this project in a few days. I will updated my post with what I find.